# Django admin pass variables to users and groups template

Tags: python, django, django-admin

I can pass a variable to a template in the admin index page via:

```
class MyAdminSite(AdminSite):
    def index(self, request, extra_context=None):
        extra_context = extra_context or {}
        extra_context['Sched_today'] = date.today()
        return super(MyAdminSite, self).index(request, extra_context=extra_context)
```

But how can I pass a variables to the admin user and group's template (`changelist_view, change_view, add_view`)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can override the `add_view`, `change_view` and `changelist_view` [model admin methods](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/contrib/admin/#other-methods).

```
from django.contrib.auth.admin import UserAdmin

class MyUserAdmin(UserAdmin):

    def add_view(self, request, form_url='', extra_context=None)
        extra_context = extra_context or {}
        extra_context['Sched_today'] = date.today()
        return super(MyUserAdmin, self).add_view(request, form_url, extra_context)
```

It is important to subclass `UserAdmin`, otherwise you will have problems with passwords. Remember to unregister the `User` model first before registering your own model admin.

```
admin.site.unregister(User)
admin.site.register(User, MyUserAdmin)
```